# Rspec/capybara - test html lang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I have scripts that define dynamically the html lang="XX" at the top of the html code.

For example even in guatemala, I have  for certain pages with htl lang="de", as they depend not on the country of the IP but on some other model's data.

Anyway, how can I assert in a test with rspec and capybara that the lang attribute of the html is "XX", which would be along the line of:

```
expect(find('html')).to have_css('[lang="es"]')
```

The actual html on the page is

```
<html lang="XX" class="deal-page turbolinks-progress-bar" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

I get this error:

```
expected to find css "[lang=\"es\"]" but there were no matches
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `have_css` matcher checks for descendants of the current scope (in your example the `html` element) that match the given CSS.  You could use the `match_css` matcher which checks whether the current scope element matches the given CSS

```
expect(find('html')).to match_css('[lang="es"]')
```

or (assuming you have no other use for html element) just do

```
expect(page).to have_css('html[lang="es"]')
```

which would be more performant.

Comment: Just to know, could you access the `lang` attribute and check it using `match`?, like `expect(find('html')[:lang]).to match('es')`?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma  You could, however if the page was dynamically changing that wouldn't wait/retry for the match so it's better to stay away from using text matchers on attribute values.  Technically you could also do`expect(find('html[lang="es"]')).to be` but the `have_css` reads better.